# How to add marks for new connections in the expandable connectors?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I got a model that uses the expandable connector as a signal bus, there are marks for each signal line, but when I connect a new block component to the signal bus, there is no mark.

My question is :
How could I add marks for new connections?
I have checked, the marks are not text labels.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "label" for the connection is actually an annotation of the connection itself. It is can (optionally) be added when a connection to an expandable connector is created. See the screenshot below, especially the part marked in red.

[image: Dymola's Create Connection UI]

What this results in is an annotation for the connection:

```
  connect(gain.u, controlBus) 
    annotation (
      Line(points={{-38,80},{16,80},{16,10},{30,10}}, color={0,0,127}), 
      Text(string="%second", index=1, extent={{6,3},{6,3}}, horizontalAlignment=TextAlignment.Left));
```

The interesting part for the label being the `Text(...)`. If I remember correctly, the `string` can be either `%first` or `%second` and describes which connector's name will be used for the label. The `index` is used to determine the point in the connection to which the label is attached, `extend` defines the placement.

The model used to show this is `Modelica.Blocks.Examples.BusUsage`.